# Default to Coldfusion page

Tags: html, coldfusion

I have two files: index.cfm and index.html

I want users to to go to index.cfm as the default, and index.html is just for when the ColdFusion server is down (fixing this is out of my control). Hover users are hitting index.html as the default, is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is usually handled in Apache virtual host with the directive DirectoryIndex  or in IIS in the default document area.

Ex.  DirectoryIndex  index.cfm  index.php index.html

The order of the files are the order that the webserver will look for the default document.

Answer (score 8):

Randy's answer is correct and I wanted to add, that if you use apache or IIS you can target the server 500 series errors and create custom directives in your config file.

**Example for web.config:**

```
<error statusCode="500" path="/index.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

**Example for Apache with `AllowOverride` your override looks like this:**

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/index.html
```